# Devise error when using a route constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rails-routing

I'm using Devise for authentication.  I have a route inside of a `constraint`.

When this route is hit, I get an error that Devise's variables are undefined.

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  constraints subdomain: 'www' do
    root to: "splash#index"
  end

  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations', sessions: 'sessions' }

  # More routes are here...

end
```

**Error:**

```
undefined local variable or method `destroy_user_session_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fbd23022208>:0x007fbd35769c98>
```

This error occurs for any of Devise's URL paths.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show the code of your overridden sessions controller

Comment: Can you show the output of `rake routes`?  Where are you calling `destroy_user_session_path`?

Comment: what url do you hit...kindly share?

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue, and I have no idea what's going on

Answer (score 0):

Try to see what `rake routes` gives you.
The answer to routing questions is almost always there.